mac os universal txt shortcut to insert 'current date+time'
Is there a keyboard shortcut to insert text that simply displays the current date and time
ive set up ones for ABN and longer email addresses
but havent found one that consistently inserts the current date and time across simple and useful mac os apps like (eg: Mail, Messaging, Notes, etc.)

I’ve heard of it but html4 1 semester at uni 25 years ago convinced me even the simplest scripting is beyond some people (me included)
